# Почему набор так "обворачивается"?

Tags: jquery, dom

Добрый день!

При работе с набором возникла непонятная мне проблема. От  меня требуется обвернуть **весь** набор в один элемент. например, надо обвернуть все `input type="radio"` элементом `div`. Пишу следующее:

Код `jQuery`:

```
$(function(){
   var form = $('form').children();
   form.each(function(n){
      if($(this).is(':radio')
         $(':radio').wrapAll('<div class="radios"></div');
    });
});
```

И, вроде, должно быть счастье - все элементы `radio` должны обвернуться общим элементом `div`. аннет! в `DOM` вижу следующее:

`DOM`:

```
<div class="radios">
   <div class="radios">
      <input type="radio" name="choise" value="yes"/>Yes
      <input type="radio" name="choise" value="no"/>No
   </div>
</div>
```

Не могу никак сообразить откуда берётся внешний `div`. Подскажите, пожалуйста!

Поправка!!! Из цикла обхода выходить нельзя!))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

неудивительно, ведь вы выполняете `.wrapAll()` при каждой итерации цикла `.each()`. Могу предложить такой вариант:

```
$(function(){
   var form = $('form').children();
   var flag = true;
   form.each(function(n){
      if(!$(this).is(':radio'){
         flag = false;
         return;
      }
    });
    if(flag){
        $(':radio', $('form')).wrapAll('<div class="radios"></div');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

[[@Spectre](/users/3159/spectre)](/users/3159/spectre), Ваш ответ верен с небольшой поправкой! Это действительно проблема вхождений. Но Вы предлагаете выходить из цикла, а это не совсем то, что нужно. Это моя вина, я не уточнил в вопросе этот важный момент. Поэтому Вам плюсую, но предлагаю своё решение:

Код `jQuery`

```
$(function(){
  var form = $('form').children(),
      radio_founded = false;
  $(form).each(function(n){
      if($(this).is(':radio')&&!radio_founded) {
         radio_founded = true;
        $(':radio').wrapAll('<div class="radios"></div>);
      }
  });
});
```

Comment: точно поставленная задача - залог успешности её реализации=)

Comment: =)всё верно. только вот теперь как вопрос закрыть=)

Comment: под вопросом есть кнопочка "закрыть", укажите причину и всё

Comment: дело в другом)моральная дилемма так сказать))ладно, надо быть до конца честным!приму Ваш ответ. а те, кто будет потом это читать пусть сами выбирают какой ответ верен.